# Homebrew: Brew Doctor Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew

I would like to install a Ruby on Rails Developments Environments in my Mac OS.
When I put command "brew doctor", I have to deal with the error below.

I searched a way to solve this error. However, I did not see similar case to mine. Does anyone know what I am supposed to do to solve this error?

If you want more information, please leave your comments!
Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is working fine: 
please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
/usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
/usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
/usr/local/include/node/node.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
/usr/local/include/node/pthread-fixes.h
/usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
/usr/local/include/node/tree.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
/usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/zlib.h

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Brew --config

```
 HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.9
 ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
 HEAD: d7aa0c0335dd67e4151503f3a29d7089c57059c3
 Last commit: 7 hours ago
 Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
 Core tap HEAD: 4b444310f26fb8350e05ca1eee54e1b39ad227c2
 Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
 HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
 HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
 HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
 HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
 CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
 OS X: 10.11.3-x86_64
 Xcode: 7.2.1
 CLT: 7.3.0.0.1.1457485338
 Clang: 7.0 build 700
 X11: N/A
 System Ruby: 2.0.0-p645
 Perl: /usr/bin/perl
 Python: /usr/bin/python
 Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
 Java: 1.8.0_51
```

Comment: should be `brew doctor`

Comment: Thank you! I edited my post!

Comment: did you try running the command at the bottom of the error message?

Comment: I put the command a the bottom of the error message, but nothing is still changed.

Comment: Are you having any actual problems with Homebrew? As the output of `brew doctor` says: "Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is working fine: 
please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!"